# In Symfony2, how to difference between two choice_widgets when rendering

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In Symfony2, I have an own type `ProvinceType` that is a choice_widget.

I have overridden the `form_div_layout.html.twig` to make some widgets look like the rest of the site.

But I don't know how to difference between a normal choice_widget (for the general choice selects that come within Symfony2) and my ProvinceType choice widget, which I would like to be a little wider.

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a specific label attr / class (label_attr) on this field in your FormType and then use css to render it your way, different than other fields

Comment: Your welcome :) You can add help fields and much more this way, all gathered in your FOrmType. Quite powerfull ^^